# Sub array core dump issue

Tags: c++, coredump

```
int proximity = 0;

for(int i = coord.x - 1; i <= coord.x + 1; i++)
{

    if(i < 0)
    {
        i = coord.x; //prevents from leaving the top of sub array
    }

    for(int j = coord.y - 1; j <= coord.y + 1; j++)
        {

            if(j < 0)
            {
                j = coord.y; 
            }

            if((board[i][j] == bomb) || (board[i][j]==hidden))

                proximity++;

        } //nested for loop runs through a sub array based on user input between 0-4


}
```

I'm trying to check coordinates in a sub array, I've tried many different variations but I can't manage to enter coordinates on the 4th row without getting a core dump error. I know it's probably one simple little line I need to type to fix this but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have performed the lower bound check but your upper bound check is missing. Your need to ensure that both your x or y coordinate does not exceed the board boundaries.

Just add an extra condition in your loop, assuming your X_SIZE ans Y_SIZE are the sizes of respective dimensions

```
for(int i = coord.x?coord.x  - 1:0; 
    i <= coord.x + 1 && i < X_SIZE; 
    i++)
{
    for(int j = coord.y?coord.y - 1:0; 
        j <= coord.y + 1 && j < Y_SIZE; 
        j++)
    {
          if((board[i][j] == bomb) || (board[i][j]==hidden))
          {
              proximity++;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: right, I didn't include anything because I couldn't get it to work properly, what I posted works except for the 4th row